# Getting protobuf current timestamp

Tags: python, timestamp, protocol-buffers

Managed to create a script and run it to schedule jobs through Google API (BigQuery data transfer service), the script uses **protobuf message Timestamp** type to set the start and end date. I'm not able to change this to the current timestamp.

Checking the below resources:

- https://google-cloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery_datatransfer/gapic/v1/api.html#google.cloud.bigquery_datatransfer_v1.DataTransferServiceClient.schedule_transfer_runs
- https://pythonhosted.org/gax-google-logging-v2/google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2.html

I've tried setting the attributes like the below, but this throws an error of "Request contains an invalid argument".

```
now = time.time()
seconds = int(now)
start_time = Timestamp(seconds=seconds, nanos=0)
end_time = Timestamp(seconds=seconds, nanos=0)
```

See a working example below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer
from google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2 import Timestamp

client = bigquery_datatransfer.DataTransferServiceClient()

start_time = Timestamp()
end_time = Timestamp()

client.schedule_transfer_runs(client.get_transfer_config("projects/{project_id}/locations/europe/transferConfigs/{transfer_id}").name,
                              start_time=start_time,
                              end_time=end_time)
```

This works but sends the request to the API for the timestamp of `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` for both start and end time - I want to be able to change this to the current timestamp.

Answer (score 5):

As noted in the [`Timestamp` docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#timestamp), there are a few ways to do this. If you just want to build a timestamp with the current time you can simply use `timestamp_message.GetCurrentTime()`. If you want to populate a timestamp with your `seconds` value then you can simply use `timestamp_message.FromSeconds(seconds)`.

As a more complete example

```
start_time = Timestamp()
start_time.GetCurrentTime()  # Stores the current time in start_time.
end_time = Timestamp()
seconds = 12345
end_time.FromSeconds(seconds)  # Stores the number of seconds in end_time.
```

To your specific instance, you should be able to do

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer
from google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2 import Timestamp

client = bigquery_datatransfer.DataTransferServiceClient()

start_time = Timestamp()
start_time.GetCurrentTime()
end_time = Timestamp()
end_time.GetCurrentTime()

client.schedule_transfer_runs(client.get_transfer_config("projects/{project_id}/locations/europe/transferConfigs/{transfer_id}").name,
                              start_time=start_time,
                              end_time=end_time)
```

Comment: So I've been playing with this and it looks like what ever I try `timestamp_message.GetCurrentTime()` or even `Timestamp(seconds=*epoch seconds*)` the issue is that the returned value isn't a new object, changes the value, which doesn't work with the API call `client.schedule_transfer_runs....`

Comment: @MeisamEbrahimi check my updated example. As noted in the docs, calling `GetCurrentTime()` does not return a new object it just fills the message with the current time.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this again, I think this is the problem then. So the API call needs it to be in its original state for it to work and the methods described only fill the values. Not sure how I’m supposed to make this work with the API call :/

Comment: @MeisamEbrahimi what do you mean the API call needs it to be in its original state?

Comment: The API call which is in my code (starting with *client.schedule-transfer*) has a start and end time that will only work when you run *Timestamp()* not when you append *FromSeconds(seconds)* to *Timestamp()*

Comment: @MeisamEbrahimi can you not pass an object to this API call?

Comment: I can only pass an object to it, it seems. If you mean the *Timestamp()* object then the problem is that the date and time cannot be changed. Not sure how else to go about it so that the current date and time is passed as the object.

Comment: @MeisamEbrahimi, can you not just build an object and then pass the object? If you post more code I can give more specific advice.

Comment: Oh ok, yeah so the full code is actually in my working example. Variables start_time and end_time is what would need to be changed

Comment: @MeisamEbrahimi updated with what I think it should be.

Comment: tried the above, but I get the below error 

`File "./transfer.py", line 32, in <module>
    client.schedule_transfer_runs(client.get_transfer_config("projects/river-island-clothing-co-ltd/locations/europe/transferConfigs/5ca6d2aa-0000-257a-9cac-f4f5e80f306c").name, timestamp_start, timestamp_end)
........
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Request contains an invalid argument.`

Comment: @MeisamEbrahimi there's usually more details, it should say what the actual problem is.